# how to monitor availability Decathlon's products with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, request

I have a request for you.

I wanna to **scrape** the following product https://www.decathlon.it/p/kit-manubri-e-bilanciere-bodybuilding-93kg/_/R-p-10804?mc=4687932&c=NERO#

The prodcuts have two possible status:

1. "ATTUALMENTE INDISPONIBILE"
2. "Disponibile"

In a nutshell I wanna to create a script that monitors for all minutes if the product is available, recording all data in the shell.

The output could be the following:

```
28/03/2021 12:07 - Attualmente Indisponibile
28/03/2021 12:08 - Attualmente Indisponibile
28/03/2021 12:09 - Disponibile
```

Is it possibile with python? Someone could help me to write the code?
I'm not able to use "request" patch or other web-scraping pythons tools, but I wanna learn.

I have tried with the following code:

```
import requests
import re

urls = ['p/kit-manubri-e-bilanciere-bodybuilding-93kg/_/R-p-10804.html']


def main(site):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for url in urls:
            r = req.get(site.format(url))
            match = re.search('availability.+org\/(.*?)"', r.text)
            print("url: {:<70}, status: {}".format(r.url, match.group(1)))


main("https://www.decathlon.it/{}")
```

but give me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? _How exactly_ does it not work? I see that `site.format(url)` won't do anything useful since `"https://www.decathlon.it/"` is not a format string

Comment: Hi! Please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please be more focused: what from your code does not work? why does not it work? what is the expected output?

Comment: I have edited the questions, the code posted does not works so it was superfluous

Comment: "Is it possible with python?" - yes, it is possible with Python. Where is the code that you tried?

Comment: I have not tried becouse I don't know how to use requests

Comment: I can see you had code in your previous edit. Regardless, you can learn how to use requests [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Comment: I have edited adding my python code and the error that it gives to me

Comment: That means your regex is not matching any pattern. Have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
import re
import time

urls = ['p/kit-manubri-e-bilanciere-bodybuilding-93kg/_/R-p-10804.html']
user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

def main(site):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for url in urls:
            r = req.get(site.format(url), headers=user_agent)
            match = re.search('availability.+org\/(.*?)"', r.text)
            print("url: {:<70}, status: {}".format(r.url, match.group(1)))

while True:
    main("https://www.decathlon.it/{}")
    time.sleep(60)
```

Output:

```
url: https://www.decathlon.it/p/kit-manubri-e-bilanciere-bodybuilding-93kg/_/R-p-10804, status: OutOfStock
```

Comment: ohh thanks it's work perfectly, but if I wanna to run the code every minutes ?

Comment: You can use `time` and a loop to run this every minute - see edit.

Comment: Thanks u!!!!!!!!!!!!! A last question: If there is a web page that have multiplechoice like the following https://www.decathlon.it/p/disco-ghisa-bodybuilding-28mm/_/R-p-7278?mc=1042303&c=NERO I could select ad example (20kg) to monitor like before

Comment: That's also doable but it's quite out of scope for your original question. You're better off asking a different question for this.

Comment: No, I'm saying you should ask a new question on Stack Overflow for that. Also, please upvote the answer and mark it as accepted if it resolves your original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230486/discussion-between-jfix91-and-papostol).

Comment: I have posted a new discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66844296/how-to-monitor-availability-decathlons-products-with-python-for-all-sub-product
could help me?